# Using Electron vs. Offline HTML5 for an offline application

Tags: html, electron

When looking up Electron and Offline HTML5, I have found it difficult to make a decision between which one to use for a project.

Assuming that a user will have to go to a certain website to download the Electron application, and would have to go to the same website to get the Offline HTML5 loaded, what are the pros and cons between using one over the other?

Some that I could think of:

- Offline HTML5 can be updated without the user consciously updating their application by just making the user go to the online page again.
- Electron would eliminate the need to code around multiple browser/browser version dependencies and quirks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on your exact requirements. The following is a list of everything that I came up with:

- electron supports module system (i.e. `require`) both in main and renderer processes.
- electron provides you access to OS APIs (e.g. `fs`). Without such many node modules will not work in the JS runtime of the browser (e.g. [`ip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip)).
- updating your app with electron is as easy as sending an [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) request. (or even better as described [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/auto-updater.md))
- an HTML 5 offline app requires a browser and the user might just give it [IE6](http://dev.modern.ie/ie6countdown/).
- electron integrates with native desktop environment (see [dialog](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md), [power-save-blocker](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/power-save-blocker.md), [shell](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md) or even [app](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md) for some examples)
- electron enhances some of HTML5 APIs such as [`file` API](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/file-object.md)
- electron lets you modify the default behavior of underlying chromium. For example you could [intercept](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md) all URLs with `file` scheme and modify them on the fly*.

In short if you want your app to have a good native integration and act deterministic (i.e. no browser quirks) I suggest choosing electron.

---

*[`electron-jade`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-jade) for example takes use of `protocol` API to compile all files ending with `.jade` on the fly without the need to prior compilation.

**DISCLAIMER**: I am the developer of `electron-jade`.